# multiple database backends per session along with db.execute when using sqlaclhemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this database connection in a fast API app.
I am using multiple binds to the same session, I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#simple-vertical-partitioning):
Query the db:

method1: working

```
db.query(Model).all()
```

method2: not working and throwing the following error:

```
db.execute("SELECT * from ...");

Exception has occurred: UnboundExecutionError
Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session.
```

This is the database connection code...
Can you help me get method2 working?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from app.settings import (
    db1_DATABASE_URL,
    db2_DATABASE_URL
)


engine = create_engine(
    db1_DATABASE_URL,
    echo=False,
    pool_recycle=1800,
    pool_timeout=20,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_size=50,
    max_overflow=100,
)

engine2 = create_engine(db2_DATABASE_URL)


Base = declarative_base()

mroi_Base = automap_base()
mroi_Base.prepare(engine2, reflect=True)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
SessionLocal.configure(binds={Base: engine, mroi_Base: engine2})


def get_db():
    db = None
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


def get_db2():
    db2 = None
    try:
        db2 = SessionLocal()
        yield db2
    finally:
        db2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below mentioned line as we would be configuring the engine while creating the respective session instances.

```
SessionLocal.configure(binds={Base: engine, mroi_Base: engine2})
```

Initialize the session class with respective engine values.

```
def get_db():
    db = None
    try:
        db = SessionLocal(engine=engine)
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


def get_db2():
    db2 = None
    try:
        db2 = SessionLocal(engine=engine2)
        yield db2
    finally:
        db2.close()
```